# How to center post title in blogger. (tried applying CSS)

Tags: html, css, blogs, blogger

I have tried several alternatives but it just won't work, even applying h3.post-title { text-align:center;}

Does anyone here is kind enough to help me out on this one time favor, i just need to align the post title at the center of the page, here is the link of my blogger which you can clearly see the post title is not centered (is it left-aligned?)

Link: http://www.andeansam.com/search/label/Editorial

i tried to replace all left keyword in my html to center, but still not luck.

[This is how i want my post title to be placed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Mw5G.jpg)

*note that the title isn't proportion to the center.

Please help me out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. It will be easier for us to help you.

Comment: Already in center..

Comment: Congrats! You probably did it yourself. Consider posting your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated my answer. Add display:inline-block; and width:100%; to the anchor element where you have the problem.

Actually, when you set the width of parent to 78% ---> It came down as css to h3 & anchor element creating problem; So its calculating center not of full length but of 78% of parent.

[image]

Later you can add css to shift the date farther below. Hope, this helped.

Comment: I am sorry, but i have updated my question including a picture. thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you once again for taking your time, i've removed the margin, but still no luck.

Comment: Thank you so much! it is no centered!

Answer (score 0):

Search for `.post.hentry` and remove `margin-top: -90px;`

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time, however the problem still hasn't resolve. you can see my html code, i've applied the code, but still not luck, the title is still not centered.

Comment: You need the text begin from the red line?